# Can't resolve all parameters for AdminProductsComponent

Tags: angular

I am getting some weird error:-

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AdminProductsComponent: (?, ?, [object Object], [object Object]).

I am unable to find the error, the and for the time the error only shows for this component not for the other components although they are in the same component.
Please help!

admin-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from 'src/app/services/items.service';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription: Subscription
  subscription1: Subscription

  constructor(
    public iservice: ItemsService, 
    private prservice: ProductsService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data => {
      this.alldata = data
    });
  }

  onclick(el) {
    this.prservice.editchanged.next(el)
    this.router.navigate(['admin/products/edit'])
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { UserResolver } from './home/home.resolver';
import { AuthGuard } from './home/auth-guard';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppRouting } from './app.routes';
import { UserService } from './auth/user.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';

import { ItemsService } from './services/items.service';
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';

import { ProductsService } from './services/products.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AdminEditComponent } from './admin/admin-edit/admin-edit.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminEditComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule, // imports firebase/firestore, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRouting,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers:[
    AuthGuard, 
    UserService, 
    AuthService, 
    UserResolver,
    ItemsService, 
    ProductsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { UserResolver } from './home/home.resolver';
import { AuthGuard } from './home/auth-guard';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from "./admin/admin-products/admin-products.component";
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from "./admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component";
import { AdminEditComponent } from "./admin/admin-edit/admin-edit.component";

const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver } },
  { path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsComponent },
  { path: 'admin/products/edit', component: AdminEditComponent },
  { path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouting { }
```

Comment: At a first glance, could not find any issue. Are all files saved? Did you try restarting the building/serving process?

Comment: Try to use relative path for importing the services in your component.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please consider replicating this issue on StackBlitz/

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor of AdminProductsComponent,

```
constructor(
    public iservice: ItemsService, 
    private prservice: ProductsService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}
```

there are two services you inject, called ItemsService and ProductsService. Most of the time, you may have forgot to add a '@Injectable()' annotation for those two services.

Comment: Did this answer help?